# improving different textwidths of facing sides with reledpar

Tags: header-footer, reledmac, reledpar, textwidth, headline

Using `reledpar` to print a modern translation with its facing Latin original results in huge white spaces between the chunks because of Latin's famous compactness and the very long paragraphs of this particular text.

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,12pt,a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[series={A},noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lineation*{page}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}

\begin{pages}
%\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.65\textwidth}


\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum[1-2]
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[4-5]
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[7-8]
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[10-11]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum[1-3]
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[4-6]
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[7-9]
\pend
\pstart
\lipsum[10-12]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages


\doendnotes{A}
\end{document}
```

A possible solution to make the result more pleasing and easier to consult would be to make the left pages' textblock narrower. This can be done by setting `\Lcolwidth` which works fine.

I am looking for a way to also adjust the `headsepline` (which I need to keep in this specific case) on the left pages and/or a way to center the contents of the left sides on the page to achieve a visually more pleasing result.

(I'd prefer to keep the `scrbook`-class but this is not strictly necessary.)

Comment: I don't see any easy way, no, to do that. Maybe I could add an hook to be executed at each pages change. But maybe your problem could be solve using reledpar synchronization setting, for example `shiftedpstart`

Comment: Thank you @Maïeul ! So I know I have to look for another solution. Perhaps I could leave the line to begin with and superimpose it later… Moving the texblock to the center will probably be more difficult. I will look more closely at `shiftedpstart` or other solutions.

Comment: Ok, centering as such is easy as `\leftskip`/`\rightskip` can be set within the `Leftside` environment (duh!). We cannot move the linenumbers easily, can we?

Comment: what do you mean by move the line number? the distance between line number and is determined by `linenumsep`, which value is the same for both side.

Comment: yes, I would have liked to change the `linenumsep` individually for the left side. But it just occurs to me that it is possible to hack this by setting `\linenumsep` to fit for the narrow left side and putting `hspace` into `\setRlineflag`. Ugly, but seems to work.

Comment: Defining headseplines for odd and even pages individually seems to be possible with `scrlayer-scrpage`. I'll read up on this...